# Nearby Places Search Requests

Tags: http, google-api, google-places-api

Can I use google places api with direct HTTP requests to find nearby places? I am fallowing their documentation 
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search
I create an api key but when I try to request HTTP from the browser like this one :
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=123+main+street&key=API_KEY

I got this message:

```
<PlaceSearchResponse>
<status>REQUEST_DENIED</status>
<error_message>
This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/places_backend?project=_
</error_message>
</PlaceSearchResponse>
```

What project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

step 1 : go to the [Google Console](https://console.developers.google.com)

step 2 : select project ( top left corner )
[image: how to select project ?]

step 3 : go to the Library and click on the **Google Places API Web Service**

[image: Google Places API Web Service ?]

step 4 : and click on the ENABLE 
[image: ENABLE Button ?]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the API is not enabled in your project. Follow [the link in the error message](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/places_backend?project=_), select your project and click "Enable".